# JRSwapFile Virtualizer swap file size remains 0kb

Tags: ireport

I am using JRSwapFileVirtualizer for optimization of memory.It creates a swap file at particular location but the size of the swap file remains 0 KB from the fetching to filling process.
I am not able to judge whether the data is actually getting cached or not..

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION` as `false` explicitly.

After that file will start growing.

```
parametersMap.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, false);
```